# how do you save from a savefile dialog in C#?

Tags: c#, text, save, text-files, savefiledialog

here is the code I am currently using to open a file using the openfiledialog             `

```
    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //opens the openfiledialog and gives the title.
        openFileDialog1.Title = "openfile";
        //only opens files from the computer that are text or richtext.
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        //gets input from the openfiledialog.
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //loads the file and puts the content in the richtextbox.
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
   System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            richTextBox1.Text = (sr.ReadToEnd());
            sr.Close();`                                                                                               here is the code I am using to save through a savefiledialog          `   

    Stream mystream;
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((mystream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(mystream);

                wText.Write("");

                mystream.Close();
```

`
             It allows me to open text files but I can't save changes nor create my own text file. no errors are shown during run time. Thanks again for the extra help.

Comment: SaveFileDialog only gives you a name, FileName property.  It doesn't do the saving for you.  Your job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `SaveFileDialog` doesn't do the actual saving for you; it simply allows the user to specify a file path.  You use the file path and then do the heavy lifting with an implementation of the [StreamWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx), something like:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using( Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew) )
    using( StreamWriter sw = new TextWriter( s ) )
    {
        sw.Write( someTextBox.Text );
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I haven't been able to get on lately, I have searched on the web for some examples and I have something similar to what you are saying. here is a link to for saving http://zamov.online.fr/EXHTML/CSharp/CSharp_302155.html                                                                                                                      and heres one for opening   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392%28v=vs.71%29.aspx                                                                                                              but I still can't seem to get it to work any ideas?

Comment: For some reason I can open any text file fine but when I type something and save it the file doesn't show.

Comment: I am using a richtextbox to write the text by the way thanks.

Comment: I honestly can't decipher what the problem is.  How about adding some sample code to your original post?

Comment: @mendez: So the only place where you actually write any text to the stream... you are writing an empty string: `wText.Write("");`.  You also never close the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: I changed my code based on what you said, For wText.Write I put (richtextbox1.text) and I disabled the close function for the streamwriter. What I noticed whenever I try to save the file is created but it is not as a text file format, it is just a blank file.  I must be missing something to create a textfile whenever I save. Not sure what to do.